# Why doesn't enter to the get method?

Tags: django, django-views

The function does not even enter the `get` method.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.views import (
    password_reset_done,
    password_reset_complete,
    PasswordResetDoneView,
    PasswordResetConfirmView,
    PasswordResetCompleteView
)
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from registration.backends.model_activation.views import ActivationView

from .views import (
    login, logout, password_reset_confirm,
    auth_pass_email,
    ProfileEditMain,
    ProfileEditContacts,
    ProfileEditInterests,
    ProfileEditEducation,
    ProfileEditCareer,
    ProfileEditLifepos,
    ProfileEditCompetencies,
    PurseTransactionWeekListView,
    AvatarUpdate,
    People,
    PopupSearchView, PopupSearchRefereeView,
    registration, identification_view,
    ReferralTop,
    ProfileSettingsMainView,
    profile_settings_notification_view,
    PasswordResetView,
    ReferralChart,
    resend_activation_email
)
from communication.views import poll_choice_confirm

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', login, name='login'),
    url(r'^login/success/$', login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^password-reset/$',
        PasswordResetView.as_view(),
        name='password_reset'),
    url(r'^password-reset/done/$',
        PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(),
        name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})$',
        PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
        name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^reset/done/$',
        PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(),
        name='password_reset_complete'),
    url(r'^pass/email/$', auth_pass_email,
        name='auth_pass_email'),
    url(r'^profile/edit/main/$',
        ProfileEditMain.as_view(),
        name='profile_edit_main'),
    url(r'^profile/edit/contacts/$',
        ProfileEditContacts.as_view(),
        name='profile_edit_contacts'),
    url(r'^profile/edit/interests/$',
        ProfileEditInterests.as_view(),
        name='profile_edit_interests'),
    url(r'^profile/edit/education/$',
        ProfileEditEducation.as_view(),
        name='profile_edit_education'),
    url(r'^profile/edit/career/$',
        ProfileEditCareer.as_view(),
        name='profile_edit_career'),
    url(r'^profile/edit/position/$',
        ProfileEditLifepos.as_view(),
        name='profile_edit_life_position'),
    url(r'^profile/edit/competencies/$',
        ProfileEditCompetencies.as_view(),
        name='profile_edit_competencies'),
    url(r'^profile/settings/main/$',
        ProfileSettingsMainView.as_view(),
        name='profile_settings_main'),
    url(r'^profile/settings/notification/$',
        profile_settings_notification_view,
        name='profile_settings_notification'),
    url(r'^purse/(?P<period>week|month|year)/$',
        PurseTransactionWeekListView.as_view(),
        name='profile_purse'),
    url(r'^referral/top/(?P<period>month|all)/$',
        ReferralTop.as_view(),
        name='referral_top'),
    url(r'^referral/chart/(?P<period>month)/$',
        ReferralChart.as_view(),
        name='referral_chart'),
    url(r'^profile/edit/avatar/$', AvatarUpdate.as_view(),
        name='profile_edit_avatar'),
    url(r'^people/$', People.as_view(),
        name='people'),
    url(r'^people/popup/$', PopupSearchView.as_view(),
        name='people_popup'),
    url(r'^people/popup_referee/$', PopupSearchRefereeView.as_view(),
        name='people_popup_referee'),
    url(r'^registration/$', registration,
        name='registration'),
    url(r'^registration/complete/$',
        TemplateView.as_view(
            template_name='registration/registration_complete.html'
        ),
        name='registration_complete'),
    url(r'^activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$',
        ActivationView.as_view(),
        name='registration_activate'),
    url(r'^activate/complete/$',
        TemplateView.as_view(
        template_name='registration/activation_complete.html'
        ),
        name='registration_activation_complete'),
    url(r'^identification/$',
        identification_view,
        name='identification_view'),
    url(r'^poll_choice/$', poll_choice_confirm, name='poll_choice'),
    url(r'^resend_activation_email/$', resend_activation_email, name='resend_activation_email'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class ActivationView(TemplateView):
    success_url = 'registration_activation_complete'
    template_name = 'registration/activate.html'

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        activated_user = self.activate(*args, **kwargs)
        activated_user.email_approval_status = 'done'
        activated_user.email_success = True
        activated_user.save(update_fields=['email_success', 'email_approval_status', 'user_status'])
        activated_user.email_success = False
        activated_user.save(update_fields=['email_success'])

        if activated_user:
            signals.user_activated.send(
                sender=self.__class__,
                user=activated_user,
                request=self.request
            )
            success_url = self.get_success_url(activated_user) if \
                (hasattr(self, 'get_success_url') and
                 callable(self.success_url)) else \
                self.success_url
            try:
                to, args, kwargs = success_url
                return redirect(to, *args, **kwargs)
            except ValueError:
                return redirect(success_url)
        return super(ActivationView, self).get(*args, **kwargs)

    def activate(self, *args, **kwargs):
        activation_key = kwargs.get('activation_key')
        activated_user = RegistrationProfile.objects.activate_user(
            activation_key
        )
        user_registration_log = UserRegistration.objects.get(user=activated_user)
        parent = user_registration_log.get_parent()
        ref_log = LogReferral.objects.get_or_create(
            user=parent, enabled=True, created_at__date=now()
        )
        ref_log.count_reg += 1
        ref_log.save(update_fields=['count_reg'])
        activated_user.email_approval_status='done'
        activated_user.save(update_fields=['email_approval_status'])
        email_confirmed_status = Status.objects.filter(verification_done=False, identification_done=False, referred=False, email_confirmed=True).last()
        visitor_status = Status.objects.filter(verification_done=False, identification_done=True, referred=False, email_confirmed=False).last()
        if not activated_user.user_status or activated_user.user_status == visitor_status:
            activated_user.user_status = email_confirmed_status
            activated_user.save(update_fields=['user_status'])
        return activated_user
```

Comment: How do you know it does not enter that method? And how are you calling that URL in the first place?

Comment: By `print` at the beginning

Comment: Make network monitoring using browser, response is coming from server ?

Comment: Are you sure you are calling it with GET rather than POST? Please show how the way you link to it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman https://github.com/torchbox/django-registration/blob/master/registration/views.py#L112 https://github.com/torchbox/django-registration/blob/master/registration/backends/default/views.py#L110

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm try to overwrite ActivationView

Comment: That wasn't what I asked. Where is the template that contains the link that you use to get to this view?

Comment: But also, show your full urls.py. Are you sure you are including the right ones?

Comment: @DanielRoseman The transition follows the link like http://127.0.0.1:8000/<activation_key>/

Comment: @DanielRoseman Added all urls.py of this app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've imported the original ActivationView (from registration.backends.model_activation) rather than your version.